# on touch event in android

Tags: android

i have a screen which is showing some information about version.there is no controll in the screen.i want to finish this activity when i tap on the screen.can anyone help me plz...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make your activity implement OnTouchListener:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener{

// All your code goes here

@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
        this.finish();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: @Viktor yes, OnTouchEvent has a deceiving name :/

Comment: There is no need to implement the Listener. onTouchEvent works without doing so.

Comment: @Pennypacker see my comment to rekaszeru

Comment: @Aleadam Thats all true. But given the scenario described in the question, where the activity holds nothing but a simple view with "no controls" it works just fine and is a tiny bit shorter .) Dont konw why im beeing such a smartass this morning. Sorry, but i cant help it today :)

Comment: i tried this.but it s not working.so instead of this i gave click event for the layout.

Comment: This worked for me after adding `((RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.parent_layout)).setOnTouchListener(this);` to `onCreate` method.

Answer (score 4):

You could override your activity's `onTouchEvent` method to finish it:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event)
{
    this.finish();
    return true;
}
```

Comment: FYI, from the Activity reference page: `public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent event)` *Called when a touch screen event was not handled by any of the views under it. This is most useful to process touch events that happen outside of your window bounds, where there is no view to receive it*. **So, if any View handles it, this method may never get called**

Comment: You are completely right, i've chose this implementation because @seethalakshmi said there are no controls just some text showing in this activity, and i assumed that way no `OnTouchListeners` will be implemented earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Override onTouchEvent in your activity.

```
 @Override 
public boolean onTouchEvent (MotionEvent e) {
    this.finish();
    return false;

}
```